# how to send validation errors in service oriented architechture?

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, architecture, soa

I am developing a service oriented application, in one of the operations exposed by my service I need to do some business validations (like date passed to the  service should be greater than 3 months in past) and send messages to user if the validations fail. Is there any guideline on how this should be sent back to the user of the webservice? Should I send a SOAP fault or an normal response object indicating that there is an failure and message with that failure.

Right now I am throwing an FaultException (OperationFailureDetail is my own type that contains the error message and if it is a critial failure, if it is critial failure user can't continue else he can) Is this approach correct?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say... it depends...

Validation errors are not necessarily "exceptional". Where I work, we don't view validation errors as exceptions, your mileage may vary.

I wouldn't say your approach is wrong, and a lot of the decision making process about what you return to a consumer of your service will boil down to how much control you have of that consumer. I.e. are you writing both the service & consumer applications, or is your consumer an outside third-party? Are the service & consumer both .Net based? Does the consumer have access to the DLL's that the service uses? All of these points will ultimately affect your decisioning.

So, no. You're not wrong, your approach is 100% valid. Whether it's the best way to handle things in your shop, is impossible for me to say.

Answer (score 0):

One usual approach is to use protocol Faults for system exceptions like SQL connection problem. The producer will understand this way that this isn't user fault and can retry in background (without user even knowing) or inform user to try again later.

Business validation faults should be normal messages and should be handled by your business logic.